# Minitest::Mock#expect without specific order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Foo
  def process
    MyModel.where(id: [1,3,5,7]).each do |my_model|
      ExternalService.dispatch(my_modal.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to test it:

```
class FooTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def process_test
    external_service_mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    [1,3,5,7].each do |id|
      external_service_mock.expect(:call, true, id)
    end

    ExternalService.stub(:dispatch, events_mock) do
      Foo.new.process
    end
    external_service_mock.verify
  end
end
```

However, `#expect` enforces that the following calls are made in the same order as `#expect` was called. That's not good for me, because I have no confidence, in what order will the results be returned by the DB.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to `expect` calls without specific order?

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but you *could* just make the order consistent in this case - i.e. `where(id: [1,3,5,7]).order(:id)`. In more complex cases, this may not be practical though.

Comment: I really don't need ordering in my case, so adding `order` just to pass the test isn't the best solution

Answer (score 2):

**Try Using a Set**

```
require 'set'
xs = Set[3,5,7,9]

@cat = Minitest::Mock.new
@cat.expect :meow?, true, [xs]
@cat.meow? 7 # => ok...
@cat.expect :meow?, true, [xs]
@cat.meow? 4 # => boom!
```

**Alternatively, a less specific option:**

Given that the value returned by the mock isn't a function of the parameter value, perhaps you can just specify a class for the parameter when setting up your mock. Here's an example of a cat that expects `meow?` to be called four times with an arbitrary integer.

```
@cat = Minitest::Mock.new
4.times { @cat.expect(:meow?, true, [Integer]) }

# Yep, I can meow thrice.
@cat.meow? 3 # => true

# Mope, I can't meow a potato number of times.
@cat.meow? "potato" # => MockExpectationError
```

Comment: This makes the test less safe. I want it to test exact argument values, not any of a given class.

Comment: Yep, I've added an example that uses a set. I was surprised that it works without mucking around with things.

Comment: Works fine for method expecting one argument. What if `meow?` is expected to be called once with `3,5` and another time with `7,9` (or the other way around)?